Unique representation as sum of an element of A and a square
Is there a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ and a function $f:A\to\mathbb{N}$ such that every integer can be uniquely represented as $a+n^2$ for some $a\in A$ and some $n\geq f(a)$? (Here and in the following $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.)
For context, for a "bounded from below" version of the problem (say, whether there exists a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ and a function $f:A\to\mathbb{N}$ such that every positive integer can be uniquely represented as $a+n^2$ for some $a\in A$ and some $n\geq f(a)$), the answer is yes: just take $A=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ and $f(a)=\left\lceil\frac{a}{2}\right\rceil$ (unless $a=0$ in which case $f(a)=1$). Indeed, every positive integer can be uniquely written as $a+n^2$ with $a$ non-negative, $n$ positive and $0\leq a\leq 2n$.

I don't get it. You made sure to say $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$ but then said $f(a) = \lceil \frac{a}{2} \rceil$ when $a$ could possibly be $0$.

@mathworker21 edited for clarity. In this "easy" version one is trying to represent all positive integers from some point onwards (I chose the set of positive integers but it is easy to say that "achievability" is translation-invariant), while $A$ is still allowed to be any set of integers (and the set of non-negative integers is chosen for the construction). You are right that I should have stated that $f(0)$ is $1$ and not $0$. In any case these are just small technicalities; I hope the statement is clear now.
